# Trying to set a background image of a relativelayout

Tags: java, android, background, android-relativelayout, drawable

I am trying to set a background drawable image to a relativelayout that i have. I am using setBackground and it asks for a drawable not an int. I can giving it a drawable and it stills gives me an error. Here a section of my code.

```
rl.setBackground(R.drawable.loginbackground3);
```

This is the error I'm getting.

> ```
> setBackground (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in View cannot be applied to (int).
> ```

Very confused please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbackground3);
```

or if you want to do like yours in that case you need to check build version(if you are building for lower version's).

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    rl.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbackground3) );
} else {
    rl.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbackground3));
}
```

Comment: I tried using rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbackground3); And i dont get any errors but it does not work. Nothing happens. The background does not change

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the drawable using that drawable reference.

```
Drawable background = rl.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbackground3);
rl.setBackground(background);
```

Note that if you're using the support libraries you can solve the deprecation of getDrawable like so:

```
Drawable background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(rl.getContext(), R.drawable.loginbackground3);
rl.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: Im getting an error on the line: Drawable background = rl.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbackground3);
              The error is: android.content.Context android.widget.RelativeLayout.getContext()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

//assuming your Layout is named relativelayout1:

```
 RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
 r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of inconsistency of library from android itself,
First, you need to create method getDrawable :

```
private Drawable getDrawable(int id) {
  final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  if (sdk >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)  {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), id);
  } else {
    return getContext().getResources().getDrawable(id);
  }
}
```

Then, create method setBackgroundView :

```
private void setBackgroundView(View v, int drawable_Rid) {
  Drawable background = getDrawable(drawable_Rid);
  final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  if (sdk >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    v.setBackground(background);
  } else {
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
  }
}
```

And finally call the setBackgroundView with drawable name like this :

```
setBackgroundView(rl, R.drawable.loginbackground3);
```